# Implement keyDown in android

Tags: android, key, back

I am making an app in which i have to use

```
@Override  
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  
{  
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)  
    {
```

in **fragment**.But i am unable to use it.
Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
              // Your code here
              return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

In you code it should come inside the if `(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)` block. Just verify if you are returning correct 'true' or 'false' values.

Comment: My class extends Fragment not Activity.

Comment: Are you getting inside the "if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)" block ?

Comment: In you code it should come inside the "if" block. Just verify if you are returning correct 'true' or 'false' values. See the updated code